Google crawler gets 403 error and can't access our website
Google search console recently started showing the error "Failed: Blocked due to access forbidden (403)" when fetching the page (rattlestork.org). Our team uses the MEAN stack, so a Docker container running an Express server is running on our server, no Nginx and no Apache in between. We are hosting at Hetzner cloud with no firewall installed. We have a robots.txt with no rules:
User-agent: * 
Allow: /

Everything is working fine,  no problems with Google Analytics or anything else. Just the GoogleBot denies its service (since approximately 21st Feb). Any ideas for a desperate dev?
I removed the robots.txt but this didn't change anything.
Solution: I tested my site with https://httpstatus.io/ and got the following error:
Missing ALPN Protocol, expected `h2` to be available. If this is a HTTP request: The server was not configured with the `allowHTTP1` option or a listener for the `unknownProtocol` event.

After falling back to http/1 the error disappeared. I keep this post up to date in case I can make http2 running with a working fallback to http/1 (allowHttp1: true was set but not sufficient)

Your server configuration might be causing the 403 error. Look into your Docker container's access settings, examine your Express server code for rules blocking certain user agents, and finally, verify Hetzner Cloud's security settings to ensure no default restrictions are in place. Make sure the Googlebot IPs are whitelisted: Verifying Googlebot and other Google crawlers

What do you mean with "Docker container access settings"? I just use dockers port forwarding (port 80 and 443), thats all.

In some scenarios, there might be configurations within Docker that restrict access to specific ports or user-agents (like Googlebot) even if the container is running. In this case, look for any middleware or routes in your Express server that might unintentionally block specific user-agents. These could be authentication or authorization mechanisms that could be filtering requests. Also, double-check Hetzner Cloud's security settings (firewalls, security groups, ACLs) to ensure there are no default restrictions that might be blocking Googlebot.
